# Titanium: How can I manipulate text of row 3 in a tableview?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

Say I have a tableview with 10 rows, and inside each row are two labels (labelA and labelB).

If I wanted to change the text of labelB in row 3, what would be the call to do that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer and putting it here for future reference incase anyone else runs into this.

Here is the answer code to my question

```
tbl.data[0].rows[2].children[1].text
```

tbl.data[0] = Data for the Tableview

rows[2] = Goto row 3 (rows start at 0)

children[1] = Goto the second child (again the first label would be child 0 and the second would be child 1)

text = the actual text of the label